# Open browser profile in robot framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Can you help me. I want to use the browser profile that I currently have. The folder location is: C:\Users\worm\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

I failed to open it using this code.. maybe you can give me the code to open the browser profile that I have using the robot framework.

here is the code that I use :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    String

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}          Chrome
${ENVIRONMENT}      staging

${PROFILE_PATH}                 C:\Users\cacing\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
${CHROME_OPT}                   add_argument("--user-data-dir=${PROFILE_PATH}")

*** Test Cases ***
Open Existing Chrome Profile
    Open Browser        url=https://google.com     browser=${BROWSER}      options=${CHROME_OPT}
```

I hope I can open the chrome profile that I have to do a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an answer, just continue discussion.

1. the line `${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable -- ...` isn't correct

   Use  `Call Method    ${options}   add_argument  --...` instead
2. `option=` -> `chrome_options` for `Create Webdriver` keyword.
3. Just in case equal sign could/should be escaped for `add_argument`. `=` -> `\=`
   So RobotFramework could understand that it is one value that should be passed as is and shoudn`t be split.

So, could you try in result:

```
    ${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument  --allow-running-insecure-content
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument  --disable-web-security
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument  --user-data-dir\=C:/Users/cacing/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
    Call Method    ${options}   add_argument  --profile-directory\=Profile 9
    Create WebDriver   Chrome   chrome_options=${options}
    go to  chrome://version
```

4. Precaution, the example is valid for Selenium below 4.10.0, e.g. I checked on Selenium 4.9.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Minor syntax issue, - you need to double backslash sign `\` in variable value in RF. [Escaping](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping)

Instead of using `C:\Users\cacing\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

it should be `C:\\Users\\cacing\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data`

or even use slashes `C:/Users/cacing/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data`.

Otherwise you will have value like `C:UserscacingAppDataLocal ...`

2. Two Chrome options cold be useful to specify a profile:

`--user-data-dir` - to specify the location of user profiles

`--profile-directory` - to specify the existing profile name.

E.g.

`--user-data-dir=C:/Users/cacing/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data`

`--profile-directory=My_Profile`

Comment: Please see my answer below, is there an error in writing the code that I used? @Sam Maksymyshyn

Answer (score 0):

I have tried what you said. but I still failed

here is the code that I use :

```
${options}=  Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()  sys, selenium.webdriver
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  --allow-running-insecure-content
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  --disable-web-security
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  --user-data-dir=C:/Users/cacing/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
${options.add_argument}=  Set Variable  --profile-directory=Profile 9
Create WebDriver   Chrome   options=${options}
go to  chrome://version
Sleep    9s
```